# Counting correct and misplaced digits

Tags: c++

This program is a "Codebreaker" game. In this section of the program, the computer checks the digits guessed by the player, compares each of them to every one of the digits in the secret code, and determines if the digit is "correct" or simply "misplaced." I can not get this section to work correctly. I wrote the code for "correct" and "misplaced" in different passes, and I know I need to replace the original variables with a letter so that one number is not checked as more than one and is instead replaced by either "y" or "z". When I run the program, the values for "correct" and "misplaced" are not correct. I am getting random values.

```
        correct_digits = 0;
        misplaced_digits = 0;

        misplaced_digit = false;

        /* Get and validate the player's guess using "get_player_code()"; increment guess counter */
        player_code = get_player_code();
        ++num_guesses;
        for(int x=0;x<CODE_LENGTH;x++){

            if(player_code[x]==secret_code[x]){
                correct_digits++;
                secret_code[x]='y';
            }
        }

        for(int x=0;x<CODE_LENGTH;x++){

            for(int i=0;i<CODE_LENGTH;i++){

                if(player_code[i]==secret_code[i]){
                    misplaced_digits++;
                    secret_code[i]='z';

                }

            }
        }

        /* Print player's guess and number of correct/misplaced digits */

        cout << setw(40) << player_code << setw(15) << correct_digits << setw(15) << misplaced_digits << '\n';
```

Comment: Is `player_code` always guaranteed to be the same length as `secret_code`?

Comment: Yes. Both will always be 4 digits. If player_code is not 4 digits, the user will receive an error.

Comment: This code is missing a lot of definitions so there's ambiguity as to what type some variables are. Whenever possible try and make your code as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `player_code` and `secret_code` will always be the same length (if `player_code` is less you will have undefined behavior) and assuming all of the code you're not showing us is correct, then all you need to do is fix this check:

```
if(player_code[i]==secret_code[i]){
```

You're checking the same character in each string. You want to compare a character in one of the strings to *every* character in the other. Your condition should be:

```
if(player_code[x]==secret_code[i]){
```

Comment: `secret_code` is being changed, so it will not match the second time, thus not overwriting the `y`s.

Comment: @super oops! +1 Good call. I was thinking he was using a temporary for output for some reason (which brings up another problem--how will we check the misplaced values the next time he gets user input?). Thanks for the catch!